# Difference between the number of rows returned and the count of those rows when using having

Tags: sql, oracle

It appears that when using a `having` clause a `count(*)` is evaluated before the `having` but the number of rows returned is evaluated after. The fix is probably sub-queries but if it's possible to avoid it I'd like to. I'm using `count(*)` to avoid `no_data_found`.

This behaviour occurs in 11.2.0.1.0, 10.2.0.1.0, 9.2.0.7.0 so it's obviously intended but I don't quite understand why. An easily replicable example is below.

Does anyone know why this happens? I would have expected the `count(*)` to return `1`.

```
create table tmp_test1 as
  select level as id, level as val
    from dual
 connect by level <= 1000
         ;

Table created.

create table tmp_test2 as
  select level as id, level as val
    from dual
 connect by level <= 1000
         ;

Table created.

select count(*) as count
  from tmp_test1 a
  join tmp_test2 b
    on a.id = b.id
having max(a.val) = max(b.val)
       ;

     COUNT
----------
      1000

select 1 as num_rows
  from tmp_test1 a
  join tmp_test2 b
    on a.id = b.id
having max(a.val) = max(b.val)
       ;

  NUM_ROWS
----------
         1
```

Comment: What's the question? It's a perfectly reasonable and expected behaviour for any database system (using SQL)!

Comment: @Ben - what did you expect it to return?

Comment: @Mithrandir, is it? I've never come across this before... My question is why? The number of rows returned clearly indicates that the having clause is being evaluated but I don't understand why the count is evaluated prior.

Comment: @Ben - in your final query, you are hardcoding the value returned as 1 - why would you expect anything else to be returned?

Comment: @Lieven, I expected it to return 1, the same as the number of rows evaluated.

Comment: @MarkBannister, there is 1 row returned. I could have used `'x'` and it wouldn't have changed the result.

Comment: @Ben - but there *are* 1000 records having `max(a.val)` = `max(b.val)`. Aren't you mixing your expected behavior between `having` and `where`? `having` only ever returns one row used like this whereas `where` would return you every row matching the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `having` clause operates at the group level - where no group by is specified, this means that it is operating across the entire dataset.

This means that in any query with a `having` clause and no `group by` clause, the results can only return 0 rows (if the `having` condition is false) or 1 row (if the `having` condition is true).

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx):

> When GROUP BY is not used, HAVING behaves like a WHERE clause.

So, it might be something like this:

```
select count(*) as count
  from tmp_test1 a
  join tmp_test2 b
    on a.id = b.id
```

This part will get you the 1000 for `count` and

```
having max(a.val) = max(b.val)
```

will get you only the one record.

---

In this case because it will get you the one record as well.

```
select 1 as num_rows
  from tmp_test1 a
  join tmp_test2 b
    on a.id = b.id
having max(a.val) = max(b.val)
       ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking it wrong...

```
select count(*) as count
  from tmp_test1 a
  join tmp_test2 b
    on a.id = b.id
```

this part will return only one row, with value 1000

```
having max(a.val) = max(b.val)
```

and this part will apply what could be thought as a where condition for what you previously got (so it will be evaluated only once), and as max(a) = max(b), it returns true.